# Vista and Windows 7 compatible Z-San software and drivers for Netgear SC101T

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I'm trying to find a Vista/Win 7 capable driver for a Netgear SC101T SAN. It's based on Z-San which had some issues with Vista originally. The [Netgear site](http://kb.netgear.com/app/products/model/a_id/2538) has links for an [updated driver](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/672) and Vista-specific [control suite](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/953), but both links are broken.

Does anyone have a link to the utilities or alternative firmware that can run this device from  Vista (and eventually Windows 7)?

**UPDATE**

The files I was able to access using David Webb's suggestion won't install on 64Bit OSes (Vista/Win7). Since you need to have the control application on every machine that you want to access the drives from, this renders the utility useless for me.

Comment: could you provide a link to the download page containing the broken link?

Comment: @John, added them in.

Comment: Whole site is a broken mess to me

Comment: @John, yeah it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something weird about the Netgear FTP server.  I can't dowload the files using my browser, but it works fine with Command Line FTP.

So,  I downloaded the files as follows:

Open a Command Prompt, `cd` to the directory where you want the files and enter the following command:

```
ftp downloads.netgear.com
```

You should see:

```
Connected to downloads.netgear.com.
220 downloads.netgear.com NcFTPd Server (licensed copy) ready.
User (downloads.netgear.com:(none)):
```

Enter `anonymous` as the user and blank (or your email) for the password.

At the `ftp>` prompt enter the following commands:

```
bin
get /files/sc101t_firmware_1_1_3.bin
get /files/scm_3_0_6_setup.exe
```

After each `get` you should see something like:

```
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for scm_3_0_6_setup.exe (7366046 bytes).
226 Transfer completed.
ftp: 7366046 bytes received in 124.42Seconds 59.20Kbytes/sec.
```

When you've finished just type `quit` at the `ftp>` prompt.

If that doesn't work, post a comment and I'll upload the files to one of the many file transfer sites.

Comment: Got the files thanks. I'll try them tonight and report back.

Comment: The files seem good, but the program won't install on 64bit OS. Looks like I am stuck with an expensive paper weight.

Comment: Looking here it seems that no new drivers are planned.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/c04b0c9d-8e7f-4270-aa7a-d16fc27a5608  So I guess you can 1. Buy a new device 2. Re-install 32-bit Windows 7 3. See if you can find a VM based workaround

Answer (score 1):

A friend has one of these - not a nice solution, but what I did with him was connect it to his 32 bit Windows XP machine, map it to a drive and then share it over the network.

All computers can write to it via the computer it is shared on.

Another solution you can use is to set it up in a VM - if using Windows 7, download the Virtual PC and XP Mode and see if you can run it in there. You should not have to many problems.

I know that these are horrible work arounds, but it should be better than having "an expensive paper weight"

Answer (score 1):

Read this article 
this worked for me
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproappcompat/thread/c04b0c9d-8e7f-4270-aa7a-d16fc27a5608

Comment: looks promising.